# Showing message box (alert) after submitig form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have form in asp.net mvc
I want to show a alert message when user submit a form.

```
public ActionResult AddMessage(Message message)
{
       If(ModelState.IsValid) 
       {
                db.Messages.Add(message);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(“Index”);
       }
       else
       {
                return View();
       }
}
```

Comment: are you doing a normal form submit or ajax submit ?

Comment: You want to show the alert even if the ModelState.IsValid is false ?

Comment: @Shyju it’s normal

Comment: @Shyju no just modelState is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `alert` method is a JavaScript method which needs to be executed on client side, by the browser.

Since you are doing a normal form submit and you want to show the alert when `ModelState.IsValid` is true, you have to do that inside the view returned by index action.

You can use `TempData` to pass some data between your current action method code and the action method/view rendered by a redirect response.

```
public ActionResult AddMessage(Message message)
{
    If(ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        db.Messages.Add(message);
        db.SaveChanges();
        TempData["Message"] = "Saved successfully";
        return RedirectToAction(“Index”);
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and in the view returned by `Index` action, you can check `TempData["Message"]` exist and if yes, read it and show it in an alert.

```
@section Scripts
{
  <script>
         @if(TempData["Message"]!=null)
         {
              @:alert("@TempData["Message"]");
         }  
  </script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But alert box appears for just 1 second.

Comment: alert will stay there until user clicks on OK button on alert. What you mean it appears just for 1 second ? What is your expected behavior ?

Comment: i know. Tha’s weird. It doesnt wait for me to click on ok button. Actually my form is in partial view. Is it gonna make difference?

Comment: That does not make a difference. At the end all views and partial views are generating HTML and JavaScript which browser will execute.

Comment: i want alert box stays in view until user click the OK button. but it disappear before redirecting to index view. is it normal?

Comment: Did you put the code in the view returned by the Index action ? You should put it inside the view which is returned as a result of the redirect. Not in your original view.

Comment: The alert should appear only after your form submission and executing the HttpPost action method code and then the redirect to the Index action/view. When are you seeing the alert ?

Comment: i really don't know. i am trying to find out. thank you so much for your help.